# Integral basis of an extension of complete fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ be a complete discrete valuation ring with quotient field $K = \text{Quot}(A)$.
Let $L | K$ be an *arbitrary* finite field extension. Because $K$ is henselian, the integral closure $\mathcal{O}_L$ of $\mathcal{O}_K$ in $L$ is again a complete discrete valuation ring.
Is it always true that there is an integral base of  $\mathcal{O}_L | \mathcal{O}_K$ that consists of $[L : K]$ elements?

I know this is true if $L | K$ is separable and that $\mathcal{O}_L | \mathcal{O}_K$ is always finite because complete discrete valuation rings are Nagata rings, but I couldn't find a result on the dimension.

Background: $\mathcal{O}_K$ and $\mathcal{O}_L$ are completions of the stalks of normal one dimensional connected schemes, proper over a field $k$.
The inclusion $K \subseteq L$ is induced by a surjective morphism of the corresponding schemes.
I don't know anything about $k$ or the structure morphism $\dots\rightarrow k$, only that it's proper.

Comment: $\mathscr{O}_L$ is finitely generated and torsion-free over $\mathscr{O}_K$, hence free since $\mathscr{O}_K$ is a PID. Since  $\mathscr{O}_L$ generates $L$ as a $K$-vector space, its rank must be $[L:K]$.